# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when run VINS_fusion

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ros

when I executed the vins_fusion source code ( https://github.com/HKUST-Aerial-Robotics/VINS-Fusion.git ), one terminal showed "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". [image] I just installed all dependencies as guides showed. I used ubuntu 16.04 & ROS Kinetic Kame. Anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Can you share which commands did you followed? and Which dataset you chose?

Comment: I just use the same command the author giving, EuRoC MAV dataset  MH_02easy.bag. I tried VINS_mono and it works on my enviroment. So I don't know why VINS_fusion doesn't.